# GWT eclipse plugin install asks for authentication

Tags: gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno on a WindowsXP machine. When I try to Install New Software from the Google plugin site  http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2, it prompts me for a username and password
The error says = Authentication failed for http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2.

I have tried my gmail account login, but that does not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 factor authentication enabled? If so you would need to use an application specific password.